# Making a portable C library interface: extern declaration vs function pointers

Tags: c

I'm building a portable C library that needs to interact with a user-defined peripheral.

Here's an example,
My library needs to use a user-defined `putc()` and a `getc()`.
To my understanding, there's two way to do this cleanly:

1. Using an "install" function that requires user to define interface with function pointers

```
// Inside mylib.h
typedef int (*mylib_port_putc)(char c);
typedef int (*mylib_port_getc)(char *c);

void mylib_install_port(mylib_port_putc, mylib_port_getc);
```

2. Using the `extern` keyword to let the user decide where to define the interfaces.

```
// Inside mylib.h
extern int mylib_port_putc(char c);
extern int mylib_port_getc(char *c);
```

What's the best way to do this?
I understand that "best" is difficult to define, but your opinion would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I disagree with the StackOverflow maintainers to flag this question as inappropriate. I don't think this website should be limited to "how do I do X?" questions. I understand that asking for opinions will probably not generate a clear answer, but, to me, this is what mentorship looks like.
When you're starting, there's a lot of value in studying knowledgeable people debating tradeoffs.
Sorry for the rent. I know your job is hard. Happy holidays.

Comment: I think you did not mention a `#define` variant. The simplest of all. I this was an intention?

Comment: Both are no good. Always, **always** ask yourself "what happens when (not if) I have more than one"?

Comment: @yvw No, honestly I did not think about it. What do you have in mind and what are the tradeoffs?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I agree with you. I now realize that my example is too simplistic. The library I'm working on would store those function pointers in a "handle" struct.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I like your mental framework for making it work for more than one. Using this mentality, I think the 1st option (+ the handle) is the way to do it.

Comment: If you disagree with moderation there is an [entire site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) for dealing with disputes. You should not vandalize your post.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only correct way is the first -
you provide a library initialize(...) function for registering user callback functions - port_putc, port_getc, maybe also callbacks for you library logging, etc.
Such an approach is flexible, and very common.

In the second case, you require the library users to define 2 functions with predefined names in their code.
What happens if he didn't?

Comment: Some `C` standard library(`libc`) writers may disagree with you. I mean if you, as a user, define(or declare) `PUTC`, then you know that you did so. That is what code writer gets paid for.

Comment: @yvw i remembered atexit(), thanks. Lets holy-war - I think this its a good example of bad design ;-)

Comment: Did not get your comment. Wording is unclear.. Holy war - it is something religous? SO is a pragmatic web resource, we talk about "real" things here. No offence please. That was about a religous part. I dont know what you mean by "remembered `atexit`". My `gcc` and `clang` `C` standard library define `PUTC` as a macros. Last time I've looked at `Visual Studio` source, they did the above too. And this people are library designers, writers, implementers.